# SQL Server backup command from Perl

Tags: database, perl, sql-server-2005

Trying to take remote backup of sql server database using Perl. But somehow getting following error :

Backup Error: 3041, Severity: 16, State: 1.
BACKUP failed to complete the command BACKUP DATABASE testdb. Check the backup application log for detailed messages.

The scripts looks like :

```
use DBI;
my $dsn = 'DBI:ODBC:Driver={SQL Server}';
my $host = 'hostname';
my $database = 'dbname';
my $user = 'sa';
my $auth = 'xxxxxxx';

my $dbh = DBI->connect("$dsn;Server=$host",
                       $user,
                       $auth,
                       { RaiseError => 1,
                         AutoCommit => 1}
                      ) || die "Database connection not made: $DBI::errstr";

my $sql = "BACKUP DATABASE testdb TO DISK='d:\sql_share\backup.bak'";
my $sth = $dbh->prepare( $sql );

$sth->execute();
print "\nexecuted";

$sth->finish();
$dbh->disconnect();
```

using the same script able to create database, query database etc. on remote server.

Comment: Did you "Check the backup application log for detailed messages"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\` in double quotes has a meaning. Escape the backslashes.

Answer (score 0):

The backslashes in your command are being processed in a double-quoted context, and

```
my $sql = "BACKUP DATABASE testdb TO DISK='d:\sql_share\backup.bak'";
```

sets `$sql` to `BACKUP DATABASE testdb TO DISK='d:sql_shareackup.bak'`. Print it out to see

I suggest you use this instead, which provides single-quoted context and allows embedded single quotes

```
my $sql = q(BACKUP DATABASE testdb TO DISK='D:\sql_share\backup.bak');
```

Comment: OK what does it say in the backup log (_not_ the server log)

Comment: Am calling this script from eclipse IDE. searched the Perl installed location and the eclipse workspace. I guess no application logs. Do I need to do some exception handling within script to check for the error(similar to java). sorry am too new to Perl

Comment: Borodin : Thanks, It started working. Not sure why was it not working. i just logged on to the two machines(sql server machine and the remote machine) using different Internet connection (from Home) and its creating backup now :)